# How can I encapsulate code that performs a return in C# MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code that returns at the end of some of my actions in my controllers. Rather than have the same code repeated many times I would like to encapsulate it:

```
        if (Session["CurrentUrl"] != null) {
            var ip = new Uri((string)Session["CurrentUrl"]);
            var ipNoPort = string.Format("{0}://{1}/{2}", ip.Scheme, ip.Host, ip.PathAndQuery);
            return Redirect(ipNoPort);
        }
        return Home();
```

One thing I am not sure about is how I could handle the return arguments. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I could do?

Comment: What about using a base controller class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at creating a custom action filter. You can then apply this reusable filter to any action method that needs this behaviour. You can apply them before or after the method has run.

Look at this [Action Filtering in ASP.NET MVC Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should be returning a [`RedirectResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.redirectresult.aspx). You should always return something that derives from `ActionResult` or you will be creating potential issues.

You could extend this class to suite your needs if you want to encapsulate some custom functionality.

Comment: I'm using the code at the end of an edit POST actions to return the user to rows of data so they can pick another row to edit. In this case I don't really have a result to return.